# Calculating Base with a Large Exponent Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

$x^{86} \equiv 6 \pmod {29}$

I have this as a homework problem and I've been searing around the internet, including math stack exchange, but all the explanations/questions I've seen have been not exactly what I need to have been too big brain for me.

I've tried a couple of approaches, including reducing the exponent and then taking the mod, but that just leaves me with the same problem. At the same time, writing it as $x^{86} = 6+29k$ just then presents me with two unknowns.

I'd appreciate some help with this! Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with Fermat's Little Theorem, or with multiplicative inverses modulo p?

Comment: You said you've tried reducing the exponent.  What did you get when you tried doing that?  Because it appears doing so will reduce the problem significantly.

Comment: @ConMan Yes, I've figured it out now. I was just confused on how it applied to this.